# Toggling a sub-menu's visibility in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm not particularly advanced with jQuery but can't see why this isn't working.

I have a CSS drop down navigation that works on hover, to add support for touch devices I'm trying to get the sub-menu to drop down on click.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="index" title="Section 1">Section 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a title="Section 2">Section 2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Option 1">Option 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="Option 2">Option 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

```css
.touch-show {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#navigation li a').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').toggleClass('touch-show');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/1/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with this code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply: https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a CSS rule to hide the sub level `ul` elements by default, then your code will work as it is.

```
ul li > ul {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tu3vpob7/)

Don't forget you also need to include the `event` in the parameters list of your handler function.

---

Given your fiddle example, the problem is because the CSS rule you're using is not specific enough to override the default styles for the `li` element. Try this:

```
#navigation ul li ul.touch-show {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do already have a CSS rule in place to achieve the same. Interestingly your fiddle works perfectly with the sample code I provided however I've created a fiddle with all of my CSS and it's not working with that. Must be a CSS problem. https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/

Comment: You're right it's a CSS issue - I've updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not included jquery libarary in your jsfiddle

you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#navigation ul > li > a").on("click", function(e){

        if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
          // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
          $("#navigation .sub-menu").slideUp(350);
          $("#navigation a").removeClass("open");

          // open our new menu and add the open class
          $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideDown(350);
          $(this).addClass("open");
        }

        else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
          $(this).removeClass("open");
          $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideUp(350);
        }
      });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLx5hhxq/4/